# Which kind of crank arm for my bottom bracket

Tags: crankset, bottom-bracket

I'm trying to make my indoor bike smarter by fitting a crank arm power meter.
The bottom bracket is a Tange bc 1.37x24t. Apparently it is of the English kind which is the most common.
Since there are many different models (Shimano, Cannondale, etc...) for the same kind of crank arm power meter, I would like to know which is more appropriate for my bottom bracket.

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct that you've got an 'English' or 'ISO' threaded cartridge bottom bracket; this refers to the interface between the BB and the frame. But you also need to consider the interface between the BB and the cranks. This has what is called a "square taper" spindle, and because the bike world is filled with competing standards, there is more than one standard for square tapers (which determine the angle of the taper and how wide it is at the seat). It looks like Tange BBs use a JIS square taper, which is widely used. So you would look for cranks that have a square broach in the middle, and that specify a JIS square taper.

But here's where we run into trouble. This kind of bottom bracket, where the spindle is separate from the cranks, is an arrangement called a "three-piece crank" and was used on all midrange and high-end bikes up until about 20 years ago. Today, most high-end cranks are based on a "two-piece crank" design, where the spindle is permanently bonded to the drive-side crank (this is lighter, and because these use larger spindles, they're also stiffer, although that may not provide any real-world benefit to most of us). As far as I can tell, all power-meter cranks are based on two-piece cranks, so you can't use this bottom bracket with one.

So if you are set on your plan of using a crank-based power meter, you'll need to replace the bottom bracket with an English BB designed for two-piece cranks, which is just the bearing cups and bearings. Something like this:

[image: outboard bb]

Note that you'll need to make sure that the BB fits the cranks. There are  different spindle diameters used in two-piece cranks.

The easy alternative would be to use a pedal-based power meter.

Comment: Made a small edit as 1.37"x24tpi threads are known as 'English' not 'British' - 'English' and  'British' are not synonymous.

Comment: Thanks, @ArgentiApparatus

Comment: As an expat, pointing out 'English' and 'British' are not synonymous is a service I've been providing to the residents of the United States for 25 years now

Comment: I'm aware of the difference. Although now that I check, I only see references to "British" BBs, and not "English" BBs. I guess Scotland and Wales use them too.

Comment: British is fine, it has many names

Comment: To be clear, the English thread is called 'BSA', where the B stands for Birmingham, and not British. It might be sometimes called British, but English or BSA are more normal. However they probably are synonymous in this context.

Comment: I've heard references to both British and English, actually. Sheldon Brown's page says British. https://www.sheldonbrown.com/cribsheet-bottombrackets.html Just for interest, Power2max did once make a power spider for the TA Carmina, which is a square taper crank, but a) they don't anymore and b) the OP's BB spindle is very much the wrong length anyway (Carminas use a 103mm or 108mm JIS spindle).

Comment: To add to the potential confusion, there are actually two types of square tapers: JIS and ISO, and they are not fully inter-compatible. You'd say something like "ISO taper" or "ISO spindle". Fortunately, I don't hear "ISO" used as a synonym for English or British threaded BBs very much.